# Trying to loop a function with a scanner class

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm a beginner in Java and was wondering if someone could help me out with this.

What I'm trying to do is trying to get to loop a user input. I was wondering how come I was getting a null pointer exception when I try to run loopPlay();

**edit: I understand now that I haven't initialized userInput. Can someone show me how to do that?**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputReader
{

private Scanner scanner;

    /**
     * Create a new InputReader to read user input.
     */
    public InputReader()
    {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    /**
     * @return the user's input as a String
     */
    public String getInput()
    {
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

and

```
class StringPlay {

    private InputReader userInput;



    public void loopPlay(int timesToLoop) {
        if (timesToLoop <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: input too low.");
            return;
        } else {
            int counter = timesToLoop;

            while (timesToLoop > 0) {                
                System.out.println("Type a sentence: ");
                String input = userInput.getInput();
                System.out.println("You typed: "+ input);
                counter--;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: userInput is never initialized? you're just calling it inside loopPlay() but you never said new() on that reference.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, you need to initialize userInput.  The line below will call the InputReader constructor.

```
private InputReader userInput = new InputReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely `userInput` is not initalized and it is `null`.

Comment: Thanks Petar. Would you mind helping me out with that? How would I initialize the userInput variable?

Answer (score 0):

userInput has not been initialized, change:

`private InputReader userInput;` to:

`private InputReader userInput = new InputReader();`